# Sort children of configurable by price desc

Tags: php, magento

Having an issue trying to return the child product by lowest price first. This loop gets the children id and then loops to get price. I need only to return 1 record.

```
if($product->getTypeId()=='configurable'){
                $childIds = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_type_configurable')->getChildrenIds($product->getId());

                foreach($childIds as $childId):
                    foreach($childId as $child):
                        $child_prod=Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($child);
                        if($child_prod->getStatus()==1 && $child_prod->isSaleable()){
                            $custom_ecomm_prodid = $this->getEcommProdid($child_prod);
                            $totalvalue = Mage::helper('tax')->getPrice($child_prod, $child_prod->getFinalPrice(), $inclTax);
                            break;
                        }
                  endforeach; 
                endforeach; 
            }
```

Also looking for a simpler method.

Comment: How are you expecting people on SO to re-produce the problem? The provided code doesn't seem to be enough.

Comment: Do you need to return the $childID or the $child when you find the lower priced item?

Comment: There is no problem. This code returns the childIds, just not sorted. Yes, return the childID of the lowest priced item when its found.